# Visible fake subpages for Wordpress private post

Tags: wordpress

I made fake subpages like in this [tutorial](https://www.placementedge.com/blog/create-post-sub-pages/).
So I have an event pages and subpage /testimonial/ which including a review form, and because its a subpage of the post(event) its allow to easy connect the testimonial to the certain event.

Everything works well with the exception of private posts. Some of events are private (private post type), so page with the event information is closed to public. However I want a subpage /testimonial/ still stays visible.

Is it any way to do it?
I've tried to catch any information at single-event-template but got a null.
I also was thinking to create extra postmeta with visibility settings, but it looks like not the best way, since it will be confused to standard WP post_status.

I will be very appreciated for any help!

Comment: Nope. If a parent page is private, the children pages will be private. You could potentially use custom post meta and checking logged in status of a user. So the parent page would have some sort of TRUE/FALSE value in the custom meta. If that value is TRUE (e.g. private) - check if the user is logged in, if not, set up a redirection to another URL or set the page content to be hidden/have a message telling the user to log in. The question is what is the actual use case for having a child visible, but not the parent?

Comment: @disinfor just to connect the testimonial to the event (custom post type). I'm getting the post_id (event ID) on subpage, and use it as parent_post ID for the testimonial, which is custom post type as well. Lets say we have closed (private) event with invited only people. After event finished all attendees automatically getting a public link to leave a testimonial. Testimonial automatically connects to the certain event and admin at admin panel can see reviews about this event.